# Having issue PHP-MySQL signup form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

After form submission browser shows just blank page. Nothing else. I've enabled error reporting. No error in php logs. Also tried (as you see) `echo $sql; die();`. Still no result. How to fix it? What's wrong with my code? My php code (which processes signup form data) looks like that

```
<?php
require '../includes/db.php';
require '../includes/ipurl.php';
require '../includes/common.php';
$page = 'signup';
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit( );
}


if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Tamam') {
    $err = array( );
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = filter($value);
    }
    if (empty($data['fname']) || strlen($data['fname']) < 2 || empty($data['mname']) || strlen($data['mname']) < 2 || empty($data['lname']) || strlen($data['lname']) < 2) {
        $err[ ] = 1;
    }

    if (!isUserID($data['login'])) {
        $err[ ] = 2;
    }

    if (!isEmail($data['email'])) {
        $err[ ] = 3;
    }

    if (!checkPwd($data['pwd'], $data['pwd2'])) {
        $err[ ] = 4;
    }

    $pwd = PwdHash($data['pwd']);

    $host       = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $host_upper = strtoupper($host);
    $path       = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');

    $activ_code = rand(1000, 9999);

    $email = $data['email'];
    $login = $data['login'];
    $dob   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['dob']));
    $age   = date("Y") - date('Y', strtotime($data['dob']));
    $type  = $data['type'];


    $rs_duplicate = $db->query("select count(*) as total from users where email='$email' OR login='$login'") or die($db->error);
    list($total) = $rs_duplicate->fetch_row();

    if ($total > 0) {
        $err[ ] = 5;
    }

    if (isset($type)) {
        if ($type == 1) {
            $region     = $data['region'];
            $school     = $data['school'];
            $class      = $data['class'];
            $group      = 0;
            $subject    = 0;
            $university = 0;
            $profession = 0;
        }
        if ($type == 2) {
            $group      = $data['group'];
            $region     = $data['region'];
            $school     = $data['school'];
            $class      = $data['class'];
            $subject    = 0;
            $university = 0;
            $profession = 0;

        }
        if ($type == 3) {
            $group      = 0;
            $region     = 0;
            $school     = 0;
            $class      = 0;
            $subject    = 0;
            $university = $data['university'];
            $profession = $data['profession'];
        }
        if ($type == 4) {
            $group      = 0;
            $region     = 0;
            $school     = 0;
            $class      = 0;
            $university = 0;
            $profession = 0;
            $subject    = $data['subject'];
        }
    }
    if (!isset($type)) {
        $err[ ] = 9;
    }
    if (empty($err)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users
(level,fname, mname, lname, dob, age, reg_date, phone, email, login, pwd, type, `group`, region, school, class, ip, subject, ban, university, profession, activation_code) 
VALUES 
('1','$data[fname]', '$data[mname]', '$data[lname]', '$dob', '$age', now(), '$data[phone]', '$email', '$login', '$pwd', '$type', '$group', '$region', '$school', '$class',  '$ip', '$subject', NULL, '$university', '$profession', '$activ_code')";
        echo $sql; die();
        $result = $db->query($sql) or die(printf("Bazaya daxiletmə zamanı səhv: %s\n", $db->error));
        $id     = $db->insert_id;
        $md5_id = md5($id);
        $db->query("update users set md5_id='$md5_id' where id='$id'") or die(printf("Bazaya daxiletmə zamanı səhv: %s\n", $db->error));
        include "../includes/success.php";
    }

} else if (!empty($err)) {
    include "../includes/error.php";
}
?>
```

By the way function `filter` from `common.php` sanitizing all posts

```
function filter($data) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $data = stripslashes($data);

    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your check for a non-empty error array should be moved up a step to right after where you check for if there are any errors.

```
    ...
    if (empty($err)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users
(level,fname, mname, lname, dob, age, reg_date, phone, email, login, pwd, type, `group`, region, school, class, ip, subject, ban, university, profession, activation_code) 
VALUES 
('1','$data[fname]', '$data[mname]', '$data[lname]', '$dob', '$age', now(), '$data[phone]', '$email', '$login', '$pwd', '$type', '$group', '$region', '$school', '$class',  '$ip', '$subject', NULL, '$university', '$profession', '$activ_code')";
        echo $sql; die();
        $result = $db->query($sql) or die(printf("Bazaya daxiletmə zamanı səhv: %s\n", $db->error));
        $id     = $db->insert_id;
        $md5_id = md5($id);
        $db->query("update users set md5_id='$md5_id' where id='$id'") or die(printf("Bazaya daxiletmə zamanı səhv: %s\n", $db->error));
        include "../includes/success.php";
    } else if (!empty($err)) {
        include "../includes/error.php";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest getting XDebug installed on your development machine, and use an IDE like NetBeans, Eclipse PDT or even better PHPStorm to try and set breakpoints inside your code, and see at what point it breaks.

You can get XDebug here: [http://xdebug.org](http://xdebug.org/)

Alternatively, take a step back, and add the following line

```
exit("i was here!");
```

at line 1, to first determine if the script is actually running, and if you can see the output, step by step, move it a line down, save and rerun the script, rinse and repeat until it breaks.

I suppose as well, although you have error reporting turned on, there could be a line of code in any of the 3 files you are including that turns it back off again like in this snippet:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

or even:

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
```